# Java: How conditions are evaluated in Bitwise XOR operator ? (^)

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I was trying to evaluate following:

1. `System.out.println(""+(3!=3 | 2==2 | 3==1));` - Returns TRUE
2. `System.out.println(""+(3!=3 & 2==2 & 3==1));` - Returns FALSE
3. `System.out.println(""+(3!=3 ^ 2==2 ^ 3==1));` - Returns TRUE - How and Why?

My Understanding:

1. Will return TRUE; on base of second comparison (`2==2`); but it will do all comparisons; unlike `||` which only do 1 comparison and return result
2. Will return false; even it gets result during first comparison(`3!=3`); but it will do all comparisons. Not like `&&` which only do 1 comparison and return result
3. ? How it evaluates statements?

Comment: This is not a bitwise operator you are using here, but the logical xor; bitwise xor is another matter

Comment: 3. `false ^ true ^ false == true`. All conditions are evaluated.

Comment: On numbers `^` is bitwise xor. On booleans, it is logical xor.

Comment: I was following : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm . But confusing name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println(""+(3!=3 | 2==2 | 3==1));
// System.out.println(""+(false | true | false));
// System.out.println(""+(    true     | false));
// System.out.println(""+(true));
```

```
System.out.println(""+(3!=3 & 2==2 & 3==1));
// System.out.println(""+(false & true & false));
// System.out.println(""+(    false    & false));
// System.out.println(""+(false));
```

```
System.out.println(""+(3!=3 ^ 2==2 ^ 3==1));
// System.out.println(""+(false ^ true ^ false));
// System.out.println(""+(    true     ^ false));
// System.out.println(""+(true));
```

Quoting [JLS section 15.22.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2), and knowing that expressions are evaluated from left to right:

> For `&`, the result value is `true` if both operand values are `true`; otherwise, the result is `false`.
>
> For `^`, the result value is `true` if the operand values are different; otherwise, the result is `false`.
>
> For `|`, the result value is `false` if both operand values are `false`; otherwise, the result is `true`.

As a side-note, the correct names [are](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22):

- `&` is bit-wise and.
- `|` is bit-wise inclusive or.
- `^` is bit-wise exclusive or.

Comment: Then what is difference between && and & and || and |

Comment: @fatherazrael If they are applied to boolean values, there is no difference. But `&` and `|` can be applied to numbers also.

Comment: Understand it now. Only 1 difference found is execution of conditions and its termination

Answer (score 1):

It is evaluated from left to right :

`3!=3 ^ 2==2` is `false ^ true` which is true.

`true ^ 3==1` is `true ^ false` which is true.

Answer (score 0):

XOR is an "exclusive or statement". How it works generally:
Take these 2 binary numbers:

```
0 0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 0 1 1
- - - - - - XOR
0 1 0 1 1 0
```

XOR will only return true if **ONE** of the two booleans that are compared is true.

So in case of boolean comparison (the logic table):

```
   ^  |  true | false
----------------------
true  | false | true
----------------------
false | true  | false
```

---

In your specific case this means:

```
( 3!=3  ^ 2==2   ^ 3==1)
((false ^ true)  ^ 3==1)
(       true     ^ 3==1)
(       true     ^ false)
true
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the Bitwise xor operator in java which results 1 for different value of bit (ie 1 ^ 0 = 1) and 0 for same value of bit (ie 0 ^ 0 = 0) when a number is written in binary form.

First it evaluates (3!=3 ^ 2==2) which is false, Then false(from previous step) ^ false (3==1) is evaluated to true.